# Haskell program that can handle any arbitrary deterministic finite automaton

Tags: haskell, dfa

```
={0,1,2,3,4}
=0 
={3} 
=〈0,0,1〉,〈0,1,1〉,〈0,.,2〉,〈1,0,1〉,〈1,1,1〉,
〈1,.,3〉,〈2,0,3〉,〈2,1,3〉,〈2,.,4〉,〈3,0,3〉,〈3,1,3〉,
〈3,.,4〉〈4,0,4〉,〈4,1,4〉,〈4,.,4〉}

Where Σ={0,1,.}.
```

I am working on a Haskell program that can handle any arbitrary deterministic finite automaton based on the above definition. I am supposed to represent each state with its name as a String, represent all states as a list of states, and represent each transition as three tuple and the list of transitions as a list.

I have modified my code and it runs but I can tell that I am not on the right track as far as the requirements go. 
I am very new to Haskell and would greatly appreciate some guidance on how I can make my code better or if I am completely off course with it. I am really trying to understand how it all works; I have gone through many different examples and tutorials but I am just struggling with my code in particular.

**Edit**: To be specific, when I input the examples given below I get the correct output except for `dfaAccept dfaFactory "10.11"`. this comes back as false rather than true and `dfaAccept dfaFactory ""` results in true instead of false. I am not seeing where my error is that causes this. Also I want to be sure that my code makes sense in terms of readability.

```
type State = Int
type DFA = ([State], [Char], State->Char->State, State, [State])

dfaFactory :: DFA
dfaFactory = (states, alphabet, delta, s, fs)
    where states = [1,2,3]
    alphabet= ['1','0','.']
    s = 1
    fs = [1]
    delta 1 '1' = 2
    delta 1 '0' = 2
    delta 1 '.' = 2                        
    delta 2 '1' = 3
    delta 2 '0' = 3
    delta 2 '.' = 3
    delta 3 '1' = 1
    delta 3 '0' = 1
    delta 3 '.' = 1

extendDelta :: (State -> Char -> State) -> (State -> String -> State)
extendDelta delta = deltaStar
  where deltaStar q [] = q
  deltaStar q (a:w) = deltaStar (delta q a) w                        

dfaAccept :: DFA -> String -> Bool
dfaAccept (qs,alpha,delta,s,fs) w =
  let deltaStar = extendDelta delta
  q = deltaStar s w
  in elem q fs
```

Sample output would look like this:

```
Prelude> dfaAccept dfaFactory “”
False
Prelude> dfaAccept dfaFactory “1”
False
Prelude> dfaAccept dfaFactory “1.0”
True
Prelude> dfaAccept dfaFactory “10.11”
True
Prelude> dfaAccept dfaFactory “10.10.10”
False
```

**Edit** I am working towards implementing these final requirements... just not sure how to get there.
a. represent each state with its name as a String
b. represents all states as a list of states
c. represent each transition as three tuple and the list of transitions as a list.
a. dfaFactory – returns a “hardcoded” DFA definition (i.e. a four tuple)        b. getStates, getFirstState, getFinalStates, and getTransitions – take a single DFA argument and return the corresponding component of the DFA.
c. getFromState, getLabel, and getToState – take a single transition argument and return the corresponding component of the transition
d. matchTransition – takes a state, a input character, and a transition and returns True, if the given state and input matches the from state and label of the given transition
e. findNextState – takes a DFA, an input character, and a current state and returns the state in the DFA based on this input and state.
f. dfaAccept – takes a DFA and an input String and returns True if the DFA accepts the input and False otherwise. Use this to call the dfaAccept1 helper function
g. dfaAccept1 – takes an input string, a current state, and a DFA. Decompose the input string one character at a time, don’t match the entire string since your solution must work for any DFA). This is a recursive function with a base and recursive case.

Comment: *I am just struggling with my code in particular.* You need to be more specific about what you're struggling with.

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having with your code? Are you getting an error message, or just wrong results?

Comment: Thank you, I just edited my post to specify what I am having a hard time with.

Comment: That was a quick edit! You answered my question before I asked it!

Comment: Side note: I believe your `deltaStar` is a re-implementation of `foldl`.

Comment: @LHM Thanks for clarifying. Pro Stack-Overflow tip: you can use backticks to format inline code, as I did in my edit.

Comment: I've just copied and pasted your code into GHCi and I'm surprised it even compiles - your indentation is all wrong. When you have a set of statement in e.g. a `where` or `let` block, they need to be indented to the same level.

Comment: @bradrn should I chance the deltaStart to foldl then? also I edited the code so that they are inline, is this how it should be formatted?

Comment: @LHM Just remove the definition of `deltaStar` (in `extendDelta`) and replace its usage with `foldl`.

Comment: @LHM I've been having a look at your code and I believe that `dfaAccept dfaFactory ""` should be `True`, not `False`, since your DFA starts in state `1`, which is also an accepting state.

Comment: You should start learning how to debug your Haskell code. [This doc](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: @bradrn thank you, for changing the deltaStar would this be a good way to write it? ***extendDelta delta = deltaStar
    where foldl [] = q
          foldl q (a:w) = foldl (delta q a) w   *** and for dfaAccept dfaFactory "" if I changed the code to make it false would that then change the other input/outputs?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, that's an excellent document. I use `trace` and (more rarely) GHCi breakpoints particularly often - the latter seems like it could be particularly useful in this situation

Comment: @LHM Yes, that is correct for `extendDelta`. (It's not a change in functionality; it's just a little more compact to use `foldl`.) I'm not sure what change you're describing for `dfaAccept`.

Comment: @code-Apprentice Thank you! that looks really helpful I am going to go over that now.

Comment: @bradrn well I am trying to figure out if I should alter the code so that it recognizes the input "" as false and "10.11" as true. As of right now my code is basically doing the opposite of that.

Comment: Your definition of `dfaFactory` doesn't match with the DFA at the beginning of your question at all (not even the same number of states, let alone the other DFA stats being different). Is that on purpose? If not, perhaps that's one source of your problems.

Comment: @danielWagner that is not on purpose.. Like I said this is all new to me and I started off with a basic/simple approach to see if I could get the code to run. I have never used/written in haskell before. So from here to make sure the two match, I think I have most but for this =〈0,0,1〉,〈0,1,1〉,〈0,.,2〉,〈1,0,1〉,〈1,1,1〉,
〈1,.,3〉,〈2,0,3〉,〈2,1,3〉,〈2,.,4〉,〈3,0,3〉,〈3,1,3〉,
〈3,.,4〉〈4,0,4〉,〈4,1,4〉,〈4,.,4〉} how would I demonstrate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You kind of are on the right track, as in your structure for the DFA is right, however you didn't implement all the specs you were given:

For starter, your DFA should have 5 **states**: `states = [0,1,2,3,4]`

The **alphabet** is right, and so is the **starting state**. However in your specs you can see that the **accepting state** is 3, so you need to put it in your code: `fs = [3]`

Finally your **delta** functions were wrong. Here's what they should be:

```
delta 0 '0' = 1
delta 0 '1' = 1
delta 0 '.' = 2
delta 1 '0' = 1
delta 1 '1' = 1
delta 1 '.' = 3
delta 2 '0' = 3
delta 2 '1' = 3
delta 2 '.' = 4
delta 3 '0' = 3
delta 3 '1' = 3
delta 3 '.' = 4
delta 4 '0' = 4
delta 4 '1' = 4
delta 4 '.' = 4
```

Furthermore, you can see that your delta can be easily simplified:
An input of 0 or 1 in any state is the same, so you can have that with a simpler pattern matching. Also, 4 is a black-hole state, that is it always maps to itself. So you can rewrite your delta as:

```
delta 4  _  = 4
delta 0 '.' = 2
delta 0  _  = 1
delta 1 '.' = 3
delta 1  _  = 1
delta 2 '.' = 4
delta 2  _  = 3
delta 3 '.' = 4
delta 3  _  = 3
```

Also, as others pointed out in the comments, your extendDelta and deltaStar are just a weird way to apply a left fold. `fold'` is usually better as it does not build up a stack so I'll use that. You need to import it from `Data.List`

So this is your final DFA:

```
import import Data.List
type State = Int
type DFA = ([State], [Char], State->Char->State, State, [State])


dfaFactory :: DFA
dfaFactory = (states, alphabet, delta, s, fs)
              where
                states = [0,1,2,3,4]
                alphabet= ['1','0','.']
                s = 0
                fs = [3]
                delta 4  _  = 4
                delta 0 '.' = 2
                delta 0  _  = 1
                delta 1 '.' = 3
                delta 1  _  = 1
                delta 2 '.' = 4
                delta 2  _  = 3
                delta 3 '.' = 4
                delta 3  _  = 3

dfaAccept :: DFA -> String -> Bool
dfaAccept (qs,alpha,delta,s,fs) w = finalState `elem` fs
                                      where
                                        finalState = foldl' delta s w
```

Comment: +1 for a helpful answer. However, I feel compelled to comment on the indentation style... What's going to happen if `dfaFactory` is renamed? Will you not be forced to realign the entire `where` clause according to the length of the new name? If you're using version control, the diff is going to look massive for a relatively small change. For this reason, I personally favour [the style recommended by Johan Tibell](https://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide/blob/master/haskell-style.md#indentation). Something to think about.

Comment: @jubobs interesting perspective I had never thought of, I do use version control but I'm just a undergrad so never needed it properly and never noticed the big diff. I'll read the guide and give it a go

Comment: True, my suggestion may be more relevant if you have collaborators (as opposed to coding alone). Shameless plug, but I once gave a lightning talk in which I briefly mentioned why I think formatting style is worth considering with respect to Git diffs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mJQdcDi7z0&t=3m25s The language used in my example is Java, but my point applies to Haskell nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful!!

Comment: @LHM You can simplify the delta even more as most jumps are +2, but thats beyond the scope of the answer, plus this way is easier to change if your specifications change

Comment: @Lorenzo I am just curious but if I wanted to implement tuples and transitions into this code, would this work and how would I go about starting that? I am currently trying to think of a way to show an example but I am blanking at the moment

Comment: @LHM What do you mean by tuples and transitions?

Comment: @Lorenzo So now that I have gotten to this point and I am starting to understand how Haskell works I have to actually implement certain criteria for it to be considered finished... I added the final requirements that I am working towards to my original post... Hopefully I didn't start off to far from the actual end goal. haha